# Redirect api.server.com to a specific CakePHP controller

Tags: php, apache, cakephp

I have CakePHP 2 installed on my Apache 2 web server.
I would like to make an API for my web app and instead of accessing it through "https://www.server.com/api/...", accessing it through "https://api.server.com/...".
I really don't know how to make it work. I tried to enable a new apache site but I can only redirect to a real location on the server while I want to redirect to the "api" controller which don't really have a location on the server.

I don't know if I'm realy clear, so if you need more details, ask me.

Thanks in advance!
Sébastien

Comment: Set up a CNAME record for `api.server.com` to `www.server.com`, configure your vhosts so that both are pointing to the same site, and detect the hostname in your controller.

Comment: What's strange is that if the user was logged in on www.server.com, he is no longer logged in on api.server.com. Is that a normal behavior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new record (CNAME) in dns zone: api.server.com to www.server.com
After you do this change, when you enter on api.server.com will be loaded www.server.com.

In your controller you can detect the hostname.

Comment: You're welcome.  I posted this as a comment, hoping that someone could elaborate on actually how to do these steps in a proper answer, not so that someone could just copy and paste my comment as if it were a full answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but i don't saw your comment.

Comment: Oh, in that case, no problem!  I had assumed you did since your post was almost word-for-word what I mentioned.  If that is just a coincidence, no worries.